# DigitalOcean - Kurento experiences

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, vps, digital-ocean, kurento

Do you have any experience with Kurento MS on DigitalOcean VPS?
It doesn't seem to work for me. Although I am able to connect, and receive ICE candidate, there is no remote video stream. 
Any ideas? Since DO has public IP I don't think I might need STUN or TURN.

Thanks in advance, cheers
Z

Comment: Check that the candidates that you receive in the client are indeed having the public IP, and that your client is generating candidates with a public IP too (`srflx` if behind NAT)

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue today with my project while the previous weeks everything was working fine.

Comment: I am using it on a DO server and its working fine, Make sure that your server is using https and it may be that your client is behind a firewall so use Stun/Turn if required

Comment: Also when i first setup my server i set the wrong address for the Kurento MS, but the logs told me that the ice candidates were be received, so check to see if the location of the MS is correct

Comment: @pazo any news about this issue? I am facing the same problem today.